# App that can sync tasks with a CalDAV server

Tags: android, project-management, user-interface, synchronization

Before I go into the actual question, let me give you some context. I am running my own instance of [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/) which allows me to host my own CalDAV server among other things. I use an app called SolCalendar that is able to sync calendars with my phone but does not sync tasks.

I am looking for an app that is able to do a two-way sync of tasks with a CalDAV type server. This app **must** have its own user interface (aka please do not suggest [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dmfs.caldav.lib&hl=en) to me. It does not have its own UI and requires another app to function properly).

Requirements:

- Must be able to do a two-way task sync with any CalDAV server (e.g. I must be able to insert my own URL to the server)
- **Must** have its own user interface

  - I don't necessarily care how it looks, as long as it has the basic things a task app should have
- Should be free, but its not a major requirement

Answer (score 2):

There is a version of [DAVdroid](http://davdroid.bitfire.at/) which allows syncing tasks with a CalDAV server.  DAVDroid is Free Software and allows for two-way syncing.  It creates an Android calendar that you can view with any calendar displaying software you like.

The task-syncing version is a bit buried in this [bug report](https://github.com/bitfireAT/davdroid/issues/34) so I'm not linking to it directly.  Note that once the bug report has been resolved, DAVDroid should support syncing tasks out of the box.

Comment: That's a nice-to-know, Frederick – thanks! I'm using DAVDroid for quite a while now, and might point to another minor handicap: if you add a new calendar or addressbook, you currently have to delete and re-create the corresponding account on your Android device (see [issue #243](https://github.com/bitfireAT/davdroid/issues/243)). Not sure how that would affect tasks, though – but AFAIK tasks are stored with the calendar, so it might be an issue here (which hopefully gets solved soon as well).

Answer (score 1):

Fastmail recommends ([on this page](https://www.fastmail.com/help/clients/android.html)) [CalDav Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dmfs.caldav.lib). It synchronises your calendar, and it isn't gratis.

The same people also make [OpenTasks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dmfs.caldav.lib), which is free and open source. I haven't used it much yet, but it seems to work.